# How to refactor an innerclass to toplevel class in visual studio?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, refactoring

I have a couple of questions regarding refactoring in VS2010. First I want to know if I can refactor an inner class and make it a top level class. Namely if I  have:

```
namespace ABC{
    Public class A{
        ...
        Public class B{
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Can I produce:

```
namespace ABC{
    Public class A{
        ...
    }
    Public class B{
        ...
    }

}
```

And have it change all references from A.B to just B?
Also if I have a solution with two projects one VB.net and one C# is there a way to make the refactoring changes in the former take effect in the later and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

After doing so research I have discovered that VS does not support these features by default but I have found a VS2010 extension that supports both of these features and much, much more. It's called ReSharper by Jetbrains. Here is a [link](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/code_refactoring.html) to their site with a list of features.

The ones I needed were:

> Move Type to Outer Scope
>
> This refactoring moves an inner type to an upper level. In case that the inner type uses members of the enclosing type, a reference to the enclosing type is passed as an argument to the moved type's constructors. This refactoring can be accessed through the Move refactoring command.

and:

> Each of our code refactorings analyzes the entire scope of the code selection to which it is applied (which can be as wide as your whole solution), including cross-language code.

And the best news of all is since the "world is going to end tomorrow" they are having a 75% off sale! Woot!